# How to properly ride over ripples on gravel roads (washboards)?

Tags: technique

On certain back-country gravel roads, a combination of erosion and tire-tread seems to create these 4-inch ripples that can repeat for long stretches of the road. Riding over them at any speed at all creates a horrible vibration that is, to say the least, extremely uncomfortable.

However, not only is it extremely uncomfortable for me as a rider to be jostled around in that manner, it also can't be good for the safety of my bike.

Is there a proper way to go over these annoying ripples without damaging either me or my bike?

Comment: The ripples are commonly refereed to as "Corrugations".

Comment: Can you skim the edge of the road? Usually washboard tapers out at the end... or heck, can you just ride off the road a few inches? I know everywhere is different, but...

Comment: @Matt Drainage ditches, fences, and tall grass are most inconvenient things, sometimes.

Comment: Another possibility is to complain to the local authority about that road.  Most councils / counties / boroughs / districts have graders that will smooth off the corrugations, and possibly touch up the shingle / gravel in any low spots.  Of course they'll only do it if money allows, and the road is past due for maintenance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- stand on pedals
- knees bent (not straight) keeping your butt 10-20cm from the seat
- your hands should be very relaxed on the handlebars (your body should be supported 95% with feet and just 5% with hands)
- keep your back straight (do not hunchback)
- look ahead
- enjoy

This works on all bicycles.

[image]

*sketch from [http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Mountain-Bike-Skills-Edition/dp/0736083715](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0736083715)*

Comment: +100 :) Those are *exactly* the things that I do, with one exception. On longer stretches of uneven terrain (e.g. 20 minutes) I get tired standing up. Then I **move my knees inwards, "grabbing" the saddle with the thighs**. This provides an excellent compromise between being supported by the saddle and being suspended above it.

Answer (score 4):

I find it helps if I stand on the pedals and stop pedaling for a bit. I can use my body to absorb the shock and keep the bike light on the ground. Sometimes riding on the sketchy gravel shoulder is even an option.

Answer (score 0):

Larger tires and lower pressure will help a bit, staying out of the sake is good for your bum.

Other than that, your going to have to grin and bear it.

Comment: Lowering pressure too much has some bad sideeffects and in this particular scenario may cause snake bites (pinch flats). Also, grinning and bearing it is not an appropriate solution.