# Are Shimano cone part-numbers sold in packs of ten and not available to consumers because they are meant to be dealer items?

Tags: hub, parts, cones

I see that Shimano has part numbers for every washer, nut, and cone in each hub, but these are sold in boxes of count 10.

Is the idea that these (cones, in particular) are consumables and one would use two and keep a stock of eight, or are these meant for dealers, and we need to shop in person rather than online to get just a pair of cones?

It sounds that it's the latter, because when I google the part numbers none of the online stores (consumer stores) show them.

**Even more briefly:**

Are Shimano cone ten-packs sold to consumers?

**Just a raving comment:**

Shimano takes the delightful approach of specifying the bolt-equivalent size. Once "M10" is mentioned, you know with certainty that the cone will fit on your axle. Beyond that you might [get away](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/83279/48599) with the race being a little off the center, but you're still stuck with the outer diameter for the cone. This seems like a task for ISO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are cheap consumable items, so the inventory management represents a significant part of the price. It's likely that a pair won't cost a fifth of the price, but much more. Based on that Shimano has probably computed that a package of 10 is the most optimal, especially given it's the kind of items that is mostly sold to shops, as you noticed.

But in the case of cones/washers, Shimano also sells packages that contain a set of cones, washers, nuts, bearings and one axle. That can be the best item to purchase for a consumer.

Comment: It's indeed clear that SKU and inventory management is a big part of the price for a small item. But that doesn't stop hardware stores from selling a single washer or a single bolt. They even take the time to put such an item on their website. They may be doing it for altruistic reasons, but when a washer is sold for around a dollar (in NA), it's clear that the mark-up is considerable (as it should; it would make no sense for the gas the buyer spent to exceed the price of the washer in most cases).

Comment: Now bike stores do not buy a ten-pack of hub parts and resell each item (for whatever they want; it's a free market). Is there an obvious reason why they want people to drive to them?

Comment: To be specific:  I am happy buying a ten-pack of cones for this bike. Are ten-packs of cones sold by Shimano to consumers at all? If yes, can you point to a single store—anywhere in the world, while we still have some level of globalization—that sells 10-packs of Sora (any style) cones?

Comment: Alternatively, can you point to a store (anywhere) that packages axle+cones+nuts and sells them?

Comment: One company, Wheels Mfg, sells what look like exceptionally well-machined cones (https://wheelsmfg.com/products/hub-parts/all-cones.html). As you see from this question (https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/83201/48599), I was unable to correlate the cones I have with those sold by Wheels Mfg (but they are very low on stock anyway, so I'd rather spend my time looking for Shimano parts).

Comment: @Sam amazon did sell that kind of package (from Shimano), but it looks they don't anymore. Aliexpress still does, apparently. An example: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4001214646673.html

Comment: @Renaud I was looking on Aliexpress too. Can't find anything at the Sora level though, only Deore/105 and up.